# nan being displayed as label in histogram for Y axis

Tags: python, data-visualization, data-science

This is a python problem. I am a novice to python and visualization and tried to do some research before this. But I wasn't able to get the right answer.

I have a csv file with first column as names of countries and remaining with some numerical data. I am trying to plot a horizontal histogram with the countries on y axis and the respective first column data on x axis. However, with this code I am getting "nan" instead of country names. How can I make sure that the yticks are correctly showing country names and not nan?

[Click here for image of the plot diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5Up9.jpg)

My code is as such: (displaying only first 5 rows)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
my_data = np.genfromtxt('c:\drinks.csv', delimiter=',')
countries = my_data[0:5,0]
y_pos = np.arange(len(countries)`enter code here`)
plt.figure()
plt.barh(y_pos, my_data[0:5:,1])
plt.yticks(y_pos, countries)
plt.show()
```

[Here is the link to the csv file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Pe4_iX2lsl3Tc3igM2Z7Pjg0zTkvkyko/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Did you check if your `countries` list contains 'NaN'?

Comment: My csv first column contains all the countries in the world and doesn't have any value Nan. I am guessing as a novice that since I used numpy to extract the file data it assumes all data to be float? Hence as the first column is all strings it shows Nan? But I'd like to know what is the work around for this if I'm correct.

Comment: Sharing a file would help finding a solution, otherwise you can use `with open("c:/drinks.csv") as file` option and use `split` option to create two separate arrays or strings and integers respectively and plot them

Comment: @Bazingaa : I have edited the post to include a link to the csv file.

Comment: @RoryDaulton: I have given the complete code which I am using. Also I have edited the post to include the file I used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works but you have lots of countries on the `y` axis. I don't know if you plan to plot only few of them.

```
with open("drinks.csv") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    countries = [line.split(",")[0] for line in lines[0:10]] 
    my_data = [int(line.split(",")[1]) for line in lines[0:10]] 

plt.figure()
y_pos = np.arange(len(countries))
plt.barh(y_pos, my_data)
plt.yticks(y_pos, countries)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I tried this and I do see the names on Y axis now but as you said there are too many countries. Hence the data is not clear. How can I split it to show only the first 10 countries?  Also, was there a way around with the code which I was using?

Comment: I edited it to show only the first 10 countries: replace `lines` by `lines[0:10]`

Comment: Thank you so much for this.